# Bitmap from filestream- Out of memory exception on XP/ Vista

Tags: c#

I'm using a filestream to load a bitmap into memory, from where I can manipulate it. The code for this is as follows:

```
try
{
    Bitmap tempimage;
    using (FileStream myStream = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        tempimage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(myStream);

    }
    tempimage.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255));
    this.pictureBox1.Image = tempimage;
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occured loading the selected image. Please check that it exists and is readable");
}
```

I don't think I'm doing anything too interesting here, but this throws an out of memory exception on XP and Vista (Assuming I remove the try/ catch that is).
Windows 8 is working perfectly. 
So far I've checked that I'm passing a valid filename, and that the image is not corrupt.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the image has already been "disposed", you are still trying to use it.

Correct with the following:

```
try
{
    Bitmap tempimage;
    using (FileStream myStream = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        tempimage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(myStream);
        tempimage.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255));
        this.pictureBox1.Image = tempimage;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }

}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occured loading the selected image. Please check that it exists and is readable");
}
```

Comment: That's interesting :) Why the heck did it ever work at all on Windows 8 then? I was under the impression that I assigning it to a bitmap outside of the 'using' statement, that it would then remain accessible in memory?

Comment: Cheers people. The using statement is deliberate (Misplaced?), as the app may load multiple images into the same picturebox1 and/ or manipulate them, and I don't want to leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the using statement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx

You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

Comment: What documentation, we don't need no stinking documentation ;-)

Comment: True, but I've always found `System.Drawing` to be very non-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fullpath);
```